# Calling a function inside the condition of an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Will the following add obj to words (edit: assuming obj is the right type AND the statement returns a boolean value):

```
if(words.add(obj)){
   System.out.print("success!");
}
```

Comment: It depends. If words is a Set that already contains an equal object, it won't add it.

Comment: Please read the doc before asking this kind of question. By the way when you call a function whether it’s in a statement (if, try ...) the function is still called and the body executed so yes the obj will be addded to words.

Comment: Depends on what `words` is and what `obj` is. Question cannot be answered as such.

Comment: I edited my post, this question is assuming that obj is the right type and the statement returns a boolean value. Sorry about the vagueness and thank you all for your help.

Comment: Still depends on what the type of `words` is. Regardless, reading the JavaDoc of the corresponding method should provide sufficient clarity about its semantics. As far as method execution is concerned: putting a method call inside an `if()` condition has no effect on how and whether or not the method is executed (barring cases like boolean short-circuit operators etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the following add obj to words (edit: assuming obj is the right type AND the statement returns a boolean value

Assuming the code can run without errors (i.e. add() returns boolean), your `words.add()` method will be invoked in the if-statement.

Methods written within if-statement will be invoked and evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this but add function should return a Boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

Question can't be answered without knowing the previous code. As the code says, if you add obj, it will print "success" on your screen, but this "if" is not the one that adds it so we cannot know if the conditional returns true or false...